# How to read all bytes from server using Indy Client in Delphi?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, indy, indy10

I am using Indy client to read the message the server is sending to me (client). It sends 512 bytes of data to me in one go. This 512 bytes of data is composed of two datatypes (Word and String). For example, it sends Word of 2 bytes, then again Word of 2 bytes and then String of 50 bytes and so on. I am trying following code to cope with this problem:

```
var BufferArray : Array[0..512] of Byte;

 if IdTCPClient1.IOHandler.InputBufferIsEmpty then
 begin
      if IdTCPClient1.IOHandler.CheckForDataOnSource(1000) then
      begin
          Edit1.Text := idtcpclient1.IOHandler.ReadBytes(BufferArray ,512, true);
      end;
 end;
```

I am getting error on line Edit1.Text := idtcpclient1.IOHandler.ReadBytes(BufferArray ,512, true); Error: Type of actual and formal var parameter must be identical.

Is it right approach I am using. I want to store whole 512 bytes on Edit1.Text and then will do whatever I want to do with that data. Please help me in getting all 512 bytes from the server.

**Update: Alternating Approach**

I am using this approach to read word and string values

```
WordArray : array[0..5] of word;

 if IdTCPClient1.IOHandler.InputBufferIsEmpty then
 begin
      if IdTCPClient1.IOHandler.CheckForDataOnSource(1000) then
      begin
        i := 0;
        while i < 6 do //Read all the words
        begin
            //Fill WORD data in array
            WordArray[i] :=  (IdTCPClient1.Socket.ReadWord(True));
        end;
      end;
end;
```

Similar approach for string like

WordArray[i] :=  (IdTCPClient1.Socket.ReadString(50));

Thats working fine, but I have to remain the connection open while I read all the data in loop. If in between connection goes, I lose everything and have to request the whole package again from server.

Comment: Use a dynamic array for `BufferArray`, change your declaration to `var BufferArray: TBytes;`.

Comment: Yes, did same. It worked. Thanks. Now I have further problems. How can I iterate through this BufferArray? I want to store everything from it to a string array.

Comment: @TLama - Updated my question. Is my new approach right?

Comment: Sorry, I'm giving up this Q&A; you're asking me to resolve the whole communication part of your client. That's what I have no time nor motivation. The document you've posted says nothing about byte order for word values nor how the strings are sent or terminated (all the things we've asked from you). To your update, why are you now trying to read word values from socket if you wanted to read the whole 512B packet before ? Have you ever seen my answer and understood what is for (by the last update, I've modified the byte order for word values) ?

Comment: @Tlama yet why u did that order reversal that tedious explicit way ?  http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/System.Swap

Comment: @Arioch, you mean to swap that word after extracting it from the byte array ? Just because was easier to rewrite two 2 chars long words in the source code than write `WordArray[I] := Swap(WordArray[I]);` :-)

Comment: @Naresh, *Is my new approach right ?*, if the server sends those 512B at once (what I think, it does), read it that way. If so, then you approach is wrong and you should keep using the first way you've had, thus read the whole 512B packet.

Comment: @TLama oh, i see, u avoided walking pointer implementation... :-)  PS. Approach is wrong - you'd not hardcode 12 but calculate it based on WordArray size. Or - use the walking pointer :-P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to answer you, unless you precisely describe what's written in documentation you have. So far we know that your 512B packet consists from 6 words and 10x50B strings. So, take this just as starting point, until you tell us more:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  I: Integer;
  Buffer: TBytes;
  WordArray: array[0..5] of Word;
  StringArray: array[0..9] of AnsiString;
begin
  if IdTCPClient1.IOHandler.InputBufferIsEmpty then
  begin
    if IdTCPClient1.IOHandler.CheckForDataOnSource(1000) then
      IdTCPClient1.IOHandler.ReadBytes(Buffer, 512, False);

    for I := 0 to High(WordArray) do
    begin
      WordRec(WordArray[I]).Hi := Buffer[I * 2];
      WordRec(WordArray[I]).Lo := Buffer[I * 2 + 1];
    end;
    for I := 0 to High(StringArray) do
      SetString(StringArray[I], PAnsiChar(@Buffer[I * 50 + 12]), 50);

    // here you have the arrays prepared to be processed
  end;
end;
```

Comment: okay, will try out this. If it worked, I will give you a big thanks

Comment: I'm not expecting it will work, the word part might have swapped  bytes and the string part expects you're receiving ANSI chars, so both is just a guess. I know exactly nothing how the strings are sent by your server, if they are ANSI, Unicode, how they are terminated (it can be something unusual, I don't know). I also don't know how those words are sent, in which byte order. You have to add these information to let me refine the answer by that.

Comment: If it would not work, I will share a word document with you which shows exact format of packet.

Answer (score 1):

1: what is the charset of the string ? is it 1-byte windows-1251 ? or 2-bytes Unicode UCS-2 ? or variable-length UTF-8 or UTF-16 ?

2: what is the length of the string ? always 50 ?

---

reading the buffer:

1. reading the manuals
   1.1 http://www.indyproject.org/docsite/html/TIdIOHandler_ReadBytes@TIdBytes@Integer@boolean.html
   1.2 http://www.indyproject.org/docsite/html/TIdIOHandler_ReadSmallInt@Boolean.html
   1.3 http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/System.SetString
2. making code accurately following types and parameter descriptions.
   2.1 Reading header: That should result in something like

   ```
   var  Word1, Word2: word;

   Word1 := IOHandler.ReadSmallInt(false);   
   Word2 := IOHandler.ReadSmallInt(false);
   ```
3. reading single-byte string
   3.1 reading buffer
   3.2 converting buffer to string

   ```
   var  Word1, Word2: word;  Buffer: TIdBytes;    
   var s: RawByteString;     
    // or AnsiString; or maybe UTF8String; but probably not UnicodeString aka string

   Word1 := IOHandler.ReadSmallInt(false);   
   Word2 := IOHandler.ReadSmallInt(false);

   // You should check that you really received 50 bytes,
   // then do something like that:

   IOHandler.ReadBytes(Buffer, 50, false);    
   Assert(Length(Buffer)=50);    
   SetString (s, pointer(@Buffer[0]), 50);
   ```
4. Continue reading the rest - you only read 50+2+2 = 54 bytes of 512 bytes packet - there should be more data.

512 = 54*9+26 - so it might look like a loop - and discarding the 26 bytes tail.

```
    var Word1, Word2: word;  Buffer: TIdBytes;    
    var s: RawByteString;     

    for i := 1 to 9 do begin    
      Word1 := IOHandler.ReadSmallInt(false);     
      Word2 := IOHandler.ReadSmallInt(false);  

      IOHandler.ReadBytes(Buffer, 50, false);        
      Assert(Length(Buffer)=50);      
      SetString (s, pointer(@Buffer[0]), 50);    

      SomeOutputCollection.AppendNewElement(Word1, Word2, s);   
    end;   
    IOHandler.ReadBytes(Buffer, 512 - 9*(50+2+2), false); // discard the tail
```

Comment: @TLama ReadString returns UnicodeString. Topic starter told about 50 bytes. There is potential confusion - and i noted in in the header of the answer. But as far as the topic starter keeps original "50 bytes" claim - it looks like that for me. Until Indy would introduce `ReadAnsiString(const codepage:word; const length: cardinal);` method

Comment: Yeah, I realized that and removed my comment... Sorry for that.

Comment: Let me correct myself and elaborate more on how I want to  parse my 512 packet. I have documentation of this packet which says there will be 6 words of 2 bytes and then there will be strings of 50 bytes. Now I have to store the words in different word array and string in different string array. Now how can I extract these things from this packet?

Comment: @TLama - thank for the comment, really. Since it confused you - it might confuse any reader. So let clarification remains.

Comment: @Naresh 512 = 6*2 + 10*50, yes ? if i did not miscalculated ? I shown you the code reading Word value and i shown you the code reading 50-bytes AnsiString. Just run one code 6 times and another code 10 times.
But you should consult documentation if the words are big-endian or little-endian - perhaps you'd need `ReadSmallInt(true)` instead. Also you'd need to know charset of those 50-bytes strings. And last - i can hardly believe those strings where exactly 50 bytes, perhaps they are C-string ? then after that done you'd have to find terminator in string and adjust its real length.

Comment: @TLama you demon!!! how you did it ? i broken my marbles trying to get both list and syntax highlighting - but could not achieve that!

Comment: @Arioch'The - I think you are reading the words directly from the socket. But I dont want this. I want to take all bytes to a buffer variable and then close the connection and then read and interpret everything only from that buffer variable. For example lets say buffer[0] = 2, buffer[1] = 0, buffer[2] = 0, buffer[3] = 40 ........buffer[511] = 0. How can I read 6 words of 2 bytes from this buffer?

Comment: @TLama - Same question to you also as asked from Arioch

Comment: @Naresh ? what would be the difference ? really ? But you can use System.Move procedure that is standard Pascal thing for decades. `Move(buffer[410], MyWordVar, sizeof(MyWordVar));` Or you can use pointers like `MyWordVar := PWord(@buffer[330])^;`. All that is basics of programming, but a rather dangerous basics. If you cannot figure it yourself by any most basic Pascal tutorial for 15 minutes - then you don't have skills to use it safely. You would just damage your program in a unpredictable and very hard to find way. Don't do it, sincerely, there are all functions that needed above.

Comment: Just keep the data in some temporary buffer and do not commit it down the line until the last string would be completely read.